# Can't create an new android project in Eclipse

Tags: android

I'm having some issues with my eclipse. I can't create a new android project after installing all updates from SDK manager. Without updates it did work normally. Has anyone else is having this issue and may assist me in resolving it ?

Comment: What version of eclipse ?

Comment: I once had this problem. I just forgot to `Help/Check for updates`, **after updating** my SDK...

Comment: What happens when you attempt? Do you get an error message? "Can't" isn't very specific.

Answer (score 0):

Open SDK Manager and select Android Support Library under Extras. Other than that, you can try reinstalling the support library and then restarting eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

After you have installed or updated SDK Manager. Do following:

1. Window -> Preferences -> Android
   Verify SDK Location path is correct.
2. Help -> Check for Updates
   Should pull updates as per your installed SDK.

Also noticed if your android plugin path has https it sometimes dont pull in updates due to changes in firewall settings, instead use `http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`

Hoping this helps.

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.

Click Add, in the top-right corner.

In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the following URL for the Location:

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Click OK.

Good luck..

Answer (score 0):

The app you designed is specific to a version.  When you update the SDK, you've changed the version of your plug-in but not the version your app is written in.  You can change the version, but it will likely have problems (ours did).